# How to define the ActionLink in VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, html.actionlink

[ActionLinks](http://aspalliance.com/ArticleFiles/1525/image020.jpg)
This Image shows type-safe method of defining the Actionlinks ,how to define it in VB.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(Of SearchController)("Search Drinks", Function(s) s.Results("Beverages",2)) %>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim,i did try that though but it showed me an error 
"Overload resolution Failed because no accessible actionlink accepts this number of type arguments."

Comment: are you using visual studio?  in intellisense, how many parameters does the method appear to accept?  I think I messed up the syntax for an anonymous function in vb.net, but i'm not currently at a machine with 3.5 to tell you.